# web based form to collect data and populate to a fillable PDF

Tags: pdf

Is there a script that anyone can suggest that would allow me to create a HTML or PHP web based form to collect data and save that data. the call the data to be populated in a fillable pdf?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing PDF that you want to populate, and that PDF just has text fields (no checkboxes or radio buttons) then [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF) may be able to help you.  You can use it as a Perl library directly, or use its [command-line interface](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?fillpdffields.pl).  CAM::PDF is not useful for generating PDFs from scratch, however.  Furthermore, if you have embedded fonts, then you need to ensure that all of the characters you plan to insert are represented in the embedded font.

Comment: Thanks guys! These were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal web page to get the data. If not sure how to do it, look for "php forms" on google, there are plenty of tutorials.

Then use a php pdf generator, like [this one](http://www.fpdf.org/), to create the PDF file. If you look hard enough, you will probably find a pdf generator that will let you use a template with placeholders where the entered data should be.